# Does SQL Azure Support Relational Databases?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I keep reading that SQL Azure doesn't support relational databases; however, I just tapped into my  SQL Azure Database and scripted a relational database.

I even checked to see what was present using:

```
select * from sys.objects
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN:

[Introducing SQL Azure Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336230.aspx)

Relational Data Model

SQL Azure will seem very familiar to developers and administrators because data is stored in SQL Azure just like it is stored in SQL Server, by using Transact-SQL. Conceptually similar to an on-premise instance of SQL Server, a SQL Azure server is logical group of databases that acts as an authorization boundary.

Within each SQL Azure server, you can create multiple databases that have tables, views, stored procedures, indices, and other familiar database objects. This data model makes good use of your existing relational database design and Transact-SQL programming skills, and simplifies the process of migrating existing on-premise database applications to SQL Azure. For more about Transact-SQL and its relationship to SQL Azure, see Overview of Transact-SQL (SQL Azure Database).

SQL Azure servers and databases are virtual objects that do not correspond to physical servers and databases. By insulating you from the physical implementation, SQL Azure enables you to spend time on your database design."

Answer (score 3):

SQL Azure is relational database on the Azure.
under the hood SQL Azure is SQL 2008 running on the cloud for you to access over TDS.
so if you want you can create an application using SQL 2008 locally (there are few [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx) though) and then change the connection string to SQL Azure and your app will work.
for more information
http://www.microsoft.com/azure/sql.mspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dataservices/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting confused with the old "SQL Server Data Services" (now Azure Table Storage) - which indeed does not support relational databases.  Developer feedback that this was unnacceptable led to the introduction of the fully relational SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Table Storage is the non-relational storage service in Azure. There is also blob storage, which is the 3rd storage service in Azure.